# Arguments sequence for reshaping 1d array to 3d for x, y, and z direction

Tags: python, numpy

I have code

```
nx=10
ny=12
nz=20
u = np.ones(nx*ny*nz, 1)
u = np.reshape(u,(nx,ny,nz))
```

I thought this should output a 3d matrix with 10 in x direction, and 12 in y direction, and for the vertical, nz is 20, however, it is not, what I imagine needs the code like

```
u = np.reshape(u,(nz,nx,ny))
```

why nz is the first one?

Comment: What do you mean "x" "y" and "z"?  AFAIK, these don't have a standard meaning in tensor indexing...

Comment: Usually, the first index is the "row" of a matrix.  So, A_{ij} is usually the ith row and jth column of A.

Comment: nx ny nz means the number of grids along each direction if I discrete the 3D item, they are like i, j, and k

Comment: That `u` could be reshaped to any order of those 3 dimensions.  You supply the names and 'meaning', to `numpy` those are just numbers.

Comment: No.... you mention an "x direction".  This has no meaning in tensor indexing.  Perhaps you are thinking of a Cartesian coordinate system?  In that case, matrices are usually indexed backwards from that.  It's row (vertical), then column (horizontal).